# How can I negate "inSet" in a Scala Slick query?

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to construct a Slick query with a negated `inSet` but I am having trouble figuring out the correct syntax. I'd like to do something like

```
val lst = List(1, 2, 3)
Query(Table1).where(_.id1 === 1).where(!(_.id2 inSet lst)).list
```

or

```
Query(Table1).where(_.id1 === 1).where(isNot(_.id2 inSet lst)).list
```

neither of which passes muster.  Is it possible to negate an `inSet` like this, and if so what is the correct syntax?  Or is there another way to construct the query that wouldn't require the negated `inSet`?  I'm using Slick 1.0.1, I expect that we'll be upgrading to Slick 2.0 within the next month.  (I can apply a `filterNot(lst.contains(_.id2))` to the query results instead of putting a negated `inSet` inside of the query, but this would complicate the function I'm writing and so I'd rather use a negated `inSet` if possible.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of

`Query(Table1).filter(_.id1 === 1).filter(row => !(row.id2 inSet lst)).list`

`Query(Table1).filter(_.id1 === 1).filterNot(_.id2 inSet lst).list`

**Related:** https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/204

**Side notes:** `where` is deprecated. Use Scala collections terminology instead of SQL terminology. Also, you are under the wrong assumption that in Scala `!(_.id2 inSet lst)` expands to `x => !(x.id2 inSet lst)` when in fact it expands to `!(x => x.id2 inSet lst)` which does not make much sense.